# How to fire event handler according to state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a grid with hover effects. If you hover over an grid-div it should set a background-color and when you hover over it again it should remove the background-color. 
My problem is once i have set the color and remove it by hovering, it doesn't let me apply the background color once more. I've tried to set my event handlers inside if statements with a 1/0 variable pseudo-switch.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: How  to make the actual event handler a toggle.

http://codepen.io/cgonen/pen/MJqVpQ

```js
$(function(){
  
  var size = 16
  var width = 600 / size
  createGrid(size, width)
  hover()
})
   function createGrid(size, width) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            $('.grid').append('<div class="vlak"></div>')
        }
    }
    $('.vlak').css("width", width)
    $('.vlak').css("height", width)
}

  
function hover() {
    var active = 0;

    $('.vlak').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red")
        active = 1;
        if (active = 1) {
            $(this).on('mouseenter', function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "")
                active = 0;

            })
        }
    })

}
```

```css
/* // Snippets section below.
// Border-box snippet */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* // clearfix snippet */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
/* // End of snippets section. */

.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    // border: 1px solid black;
}
.grid {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
.vlak {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/* // questions for myself:
// Why setting border changes total size of div? I've set box-sizing to border-box or content-box accordingly,
// but that didn't work forcing me to use 'outline'.  */
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width", initiat-scale="1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="header">
            <h1>HoverMatic</h1>
            <p>General description placeholder</p>
            <input type="number" value="16" placeholder="grid size">
            <select name="colors" id="">
                <option value="black">black</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="pink">pink</option>
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
            </select>
            <button>clear grid</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: why are you bind a event inside another event?

Comment: I thought that if statements only run once and thought that nesting an event inside another would keep it 'active' (looping) as a possible solution. Tried many things.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class to toggle the color:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var size = 16
  var width = 600 / size
  createGrid(size, width)
  hover()
})
   function createGrid(size, width) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            $('.grid').append('<div class="vlak"></div>')
        }
    }
    $('.vlak').css("width", width)
    $('.vlak').css("height", width)
}

  
function hover() {
    $('.vlak').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    })

}
```

```css
/* // Snippets section below.
// Border-box snippet */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* // clearfix snippet */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
/* // End of snippets section. */

.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    // border: 1px solid black;
}
.grid {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
.vlak {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
  }
/* // questions for myself:
// Why setting border changes total size of div? I've set box-sizing to border-box or content-box accordingly,
// but that didn't work forcing me to use 'outline'.  */
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width", initiat-scale="1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="header">
            <h1>HoverMatic</h1>
            <p>General description placeholder</p>
            <input type="number" value="16" placeholder="grid size">
            <select name="colors" id="">
                <option value="black">black</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="pink">pink</option>
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
            </select>
            <button>clear grid</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

You may be looking for something like:

```js
$(function() {

  var size = 16
  var width = 600 / size
  createGrid(size, width)
  hover()
})

function createGrid(size, width) {
  for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      $('.grid').append('<div class="vlak"></div>')
    }
  }
  $('.vlak').css("width", width)
  $('.vlak').css("height", width)
}


function hover() {
  var isActive = false;
  $('.vlak').on('click', function() {
    isActive = !isActive;
  })
  $('.vlak').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if (isActive) {
      $(this).toggleClass('red');
    }
  })

}
```

```css
/* // Snippets section below.
// Border-box snippet */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
/* // clearfix snippet */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/* // End of snippets section. */

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  // border: 1px solid black;

}
.grid {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.vlak {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
/* // questions for myself:
// Why setting border changes total size of div? I've set box-sizing to border-box or content-box accordingly,
// but that didn't work forcing me to use 'outline'.  */
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initiat-scale="1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
      <h1>HoverMatic</h1>
      <p>General description placeholder</p>
      <input type="number" value="16" placeholder="grid size">
      <select name="colors" id="">
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="pink">pink</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
      </select>
      <button>clear grid</button>
    </div>
    <div class="grid clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks! this works, but how to make it a 'toggle event handler'?

Comment: what do you mean by toggle?

Comment: the .toggleClass keeps listening to see the state of red class forever. I want the event handlers to be a toggle like that too, running forever to keep checking the state of the active variable. Now it runs just once, it seems. I can only hover over it to apply red and hover again to remove just Once.

Comment: as long as the page is open the event will trigger, i don't understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to attach a second event listener; and also you need `===` for testing equality: `x = 1` is an assignment.

```
function hover() {
    var active = 0;

    $('.vlak').on('mouseenter', function () {
        if (active == 1) {
          $(this).css("background-color", "")
          active = 0;
        }

        else {
          $(this).css("background-color", "red")
          active = 1;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: @Hyrule I tested this on your codepen, and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your hover method little bit and i hope this will solve your issue.

```
function hover() {

$('.vlak').on('mouseenter', function () {
    if(this.getAttribute("style").indexOf('red') < 0) {

        $(this).css("background-color", "red")
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
})

}
```

Please let me know this is helpful or not ?

You can see live demo

[Code pen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNOLZZ)